# Node moving when pivot is inside the geometry of another node

Tags: ios, scenekit

My scene contains;
A static body at the root of the scene

```
_firstNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
_firstNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
_firstNode.geometry = [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:950];
_firstNode.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor greenColor];
_firstNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody staticBody];
 [[scene rootNode] addChildNode:_firstNode];
```

A dynamic body with it's pivot property at (0,-1200,0)

```
_secondNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
_secondNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
_secondNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -1200, 0);
_secondNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody];
_secondNode.physicsBody.physicsShape = [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:[SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:2] options:nil];
[[scene rootNode] addChildNode:_secondNode];
```

Since both nodes are children of the rootNode the pivot is located in the centre of the static node. The idea is to run a SCNAction that rotates _secondNode around the _firstNode about it's X axis and applyTorque as needed to rotate about it's Y axis.

That code is fine for the moment, the problem is that while _firstNode remains static, it is pushing _secondNode.pivot to the surface of _firstNode's geometry. However simply taking around _firstNode's physicsBody away doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Does the _secondNode rotate around the _firstNode completely?  It looks like the _secondNode sits right on top of the _firstNode with a pivot (which it should rotate around) at -1200 on the x axis. Seems like it would rotate way out away from the _firstNode and circle back to where it started from directly on top of the _firstNode again.

Comment: When I set _secondNode's mass to 0, it is positioned and rotates perfectly around as intended with the given properties. However without mass i cannot use physics. It seems that it's a collision pushing _secondNode's pivot outside _firstNode's geometry, but when i set their collision and category bit mask to ignore collision it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I left an answer. Set your mass back up and try check out my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it is getting too much friction as it is trying to spin. Try setting your angularDamping down to 0. Its default is 0.1. The angularDamping simulates the amount of friction as an object spins. A value of 0 simulates no friction (spin for ever). A value of 1.0 simulates 100% friction or static basically.

Set it like so...

```
yourNode.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0
```