# Orbiting bodies using scenekit physics

Tags: ios, physics, game-physics, scenekit

After countless attempts to get one node to orbit another using simple mechanics I have stumbled into too many limitations of scenekit which just makes it more complicated.

I have now bit the bullet to make it completely physics based.

I am looking to setup a physics world that all that is needed is one node to orbit another with the orbit radius to be adjustable. Gravity is not a must in this project if that would simplify the process.

My attempts at this haven't resulted in what I am after. I am at a loss to what force to apply to achieve this. I have tried a multitude of different combinations of force, torque and gravity.

Note: I have looked at other questions and researched for quite some time, but all answers depicted a much more complicated physics world than is needed and/or needed a physics degree to understand.

Comment: Do you want an actual physics simulation of orbiting bodies, or do you just want an animation where one circles another?

Comment: Physics simulation seems to be my only option, any attempts I've made to use anything else has resulted in problems, either with node space or collisions.

Comment: I would say if all you need is to have the visual effect of orbitting, you could just define one to be the center and the other follow an elliptical path around it. I am not understanding the issue. You need to add more information in order for us to better help you.

Comment: The question is clear. I had other questions open to find solutions to issues that arose with different approaches I have attempted (including the one you have stated). The community demands this question be solely about physics simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it this way:
-Create a central node

-Create the orbiting node

-set the orbiting node as the subnode of the central node

-move the subnode away from the central node in any direction

-CHANGE the pivot point of the orbiting node to be at in the middle of the central node

-add a constant animation to the orbiting node [Orbitingnode runaction:[SCNAction rotateBy x:y:z: duration]];

that should do it

Comment: As stated I have used many different approaches to achieve the effect i am looking for, including the one you suggest. Questions on this approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080369/node-moving-when-pivot-is-inside-the-geometry-of-another-node)

Comment: Also the other issue with this is I need the ability to rotate the orbiting node, changing the direction of momentum. I hadn't mentioned this as this question is clearly about physics simulation.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a distance constraint given a max and min distance and then give the orbiting node an impulse in the desired direction. You may also be able to use a physics hinge joint.